# How to control array keys when using array_push()?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$date_data = array(
                $date_title => array(
                    'title' => get_field('jahr'),
                    'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
            )
);
```

This array is within a loop and gets pushed to the array `$archive_years`. If the value of `$date_title` already exists as a key in the array, I don't want it to be duplicated, so the values should be pushed to the existing key.

For now this is what happens:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020 - 2010"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(4) "2013"
      ["permalink"]=>
      string(68) "http://example.com"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020 - 2010"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(4) "2016"
      ["permalink"]=>
      string(66) "http://example.com/example"
    }
  }
}
```

As you see `2020 - 2010` is listed twice. How can I assign my values (`get_field('jahr')` and `get_the_permalink()`) to the existing key, so there are no duplicated keys?

This is the whole code:

```
$archive_years = array();
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'archiv');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();        

    // Specify the interval
    $date_up = ceil(get_field('jahr') / 10) * 10;
    $date_down = ceil(get_field('jahr') / 10) * 10 - 10;
    $date_title = $date_up . ' - ' . $date_down;

    $date_data = array(
                    $date_title => array(
                        'title' => get_field('jahr'),
                        'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                )
    );
    if (!array_key_exists($date_title, $archive_years)) { 
        array_push($archive_years, $date_data);
    }

endwhile;

foreach ($archive_years as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        echo '
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info collapsible" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#archiv_'. $v['title'] .'">'. $k .'</button>
            <div id="archiv_'. $v['title'] .'" class="collapse">
                <a href="'. $v["permalink"] .'">'. $v["title"] .'</a><br>
            </div>';
    }
}

var_dump($archive_years);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `array_merge` instead of `array_push`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: When using `array_merge($archive_years, $date_data);` var_dump returns `array(0) { }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020 - 2010"]=> ...
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2020 - 2010"]=> ...
  }
}
```

This array structure is nonsense for your purposes. You want one fewer levels of arrays, just:

```
array(0) {
  ["2020 - 2010"]=> ...
}
```

To achieve this, just do:

```
$archive_years[$date_title] = array(
    'title' => get_field('jahr'),
    'permalink' => get_the_permalink()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can check if the key exists and push it to the array:

```
if (!array_key_exists($date_title, $archive_years)) {
    $archive_years[$date_title] = array();
}
array_push($archive_years[$date_title], $date_data);
```

Answer (score -1):

You simply have an error in your logic.  Consider this excerpt of your code:

```
$date_title => array(
                    'title' => get_field('jahr'),
                    'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
            )
);
if (!array_key_exists($date_title, $archive_years)) {
```

Recall that the [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) definition of `array_key_exists()` is as follows:

```
bool array_key_exists (mixed $key, array $search)
```

Therefore, what you are attempting to use as "an array *key"* is an array, itself. You can't do that. *(But, PHP might not tell you that. It might simply do the wrong thing.)*

You are going to have to include a *loop* that searches through your array, deep-comparing each element against `$date_title` to determine if it already exists. Or, you might wish to use *another* array, say indexed by `title`, to quickly determine whether-or-not a particular title has been mentioned before.

Extending the above notion still further, you could index that "another array" by a *concatenation* of both `title` and `permalink` in order to quickly detect that any *combination* of the two values has appeared before.

In any case, a modification to your program's design is necessary.

Comment: You certainly **can** "do that" as in use an *array* as a *key* to `array_key_exists`, that is exactly what the *mixed* keyword means.  It is probably not what he *intends* in this case however.

Comment: I was not aware that an array would work in this case.  (And, I certainly would not *do* it.)

Comment: actually it doesn't, i misspoke.  I thought it worked here but it actually only means *string* or *int* in this case.